# Getting Elevation Data for Elevation Attribute using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro, elevation

In ArcGIS Pro, how can I insert the elevation data into an attribute table?

There is already an elevation field created, and the feature class is set to where all features are on the ground, so you would think that when features are created that they would automatically take on the ground elevation. I feel like this is the case, anyway, but I just can't figure out how to get this data into the attribute table.

There isn't a Z coordinate system set on the map, but the XY is in North Carolina StatePlane.

I have elevation data for other points in the feature class, but that's because I got them straight from surveyors.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a basic 3D Analyst license you can use [Add Surface Information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-surface-information.htm) to populate the attribute table of a feature class with the Z value of the surface of your choice.  Keep in mind that this tool (like all ESRI tools that have a vector to raster interface) will require that your two datasets share a coordinate reference system.

If you do not have a 3D Analyst license you can always use open-source alternatives.  SAGA has an Add Grid to Points tool that can be accessed using SAGA or via the SAGA tools available in the processing tools of QGIS.